# Why when i use iperf3 at ubuntu between client-server it mesaured the bitrate and not the bandwidth?

Tags: ubuntu, bandwidth, sdn, iperf3

When i try to run iperf3 at ubuntu between client-server mode, it shows me the bitrate?
I cant measure the Bandwidth with iperf3? Only with iperf?

I run the ONOS controller with a fattrew topology, and i tried to measured the bandqidth with iperf3, at client-server mode, but it shows only bitrate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwlaW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KdSH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xSKo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iperf/iperf3/netperf/whatnot can report only what they are able to see/measure.  And in this case it happens to be the rate at which the iperf3 client can send data to the iperf3 server.  It chooses by default to provide that answer in units of bits per second.  You can see it is also reporting how many bytes were sent/received over that reporting interval.  I know there are options to netperf to alter the reporting units for transfer rate.  I assume there are similar options in iperf/iperf3 which would be described in their documentation.

iperf/iperf3/netperf do not truly know how TCP will be segmenting the traffic being sent, nor if there are other headers being used, so they cannot report how much link "bandwidth" is being consumed.